# send custom product price to checkout on add to cart in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, price, addtocart

I have a `custom price` in phtml which is shown in the product page.Now I want to send that price to checkout page on add to cart click in `magento2` that custom price is coming in js variable and input text field name. If anyone knows reply to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [`checkout_cart_product_add_after`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L406) event for this, in this event you will get `quote_item` (added product into the cart by the customer).

So first you need to create `events.xml` , in this file you need to define your event

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="change_price_add_to_cart" instance="Example\Sample\Observer\ChangePrice" />
</event>
```

Now you need to create your Observer so you can change your price,

```
<?php

namespace Example\Sample\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangePrice implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $customerPrice = 9.99; //do your magic here for custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($customerPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customerPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set that custom price using Event. See how to use Events and observers checkout magento link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Run an observer on the event on `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and set custom price which is post from form. Magento has store add to cart form posted fields value at Quote item object's **buying request metho**d `$quoteItem->getBuyRequest()`.At **your observer, you can get that  custom price input field value easily than using quote item `setCustomPrice()` method you can set your custom  price**.

```
<?php
    namespace Devbera\CarPrice\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $quoteItem = ( $quoteItem->getParentItem() ? $quoteItem->getParentItem() : $quoteItem );
        $buyRequest = $quoteItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_object($buyRequest)) {
                $buyRequestArray = $buyRequest->toArray();

                if (array_key_exists('custom_price_field', $buyRequestArray)) {
            $price = $buyRequestArray['custom_price_field'];
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                }
            }       

        }

    }
```

Comment: i want to do it with controller nor observer

Comment: just a few seconds you are faster Master Amit :)

Comment: You have to use observer

Comment: Don't Call me as master :).I am a developer like you

Comment: @AmitBera, please help on this issue, its similar issue like above, but quoteid not retrieving,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2